# page.waitForFunction not working as expected - npm puppeteer

Tags: node.js, rest, npm, puppeteer

I have 2 function to wait in my script

```js
    // Wait for message to show up
    page.waitForFunction("document.querySelector('div#message').textContent.includes('string inside message')")
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(404).json({ success: true, data: null, message: 'Message' });
        });

    // Wait for result to show up after clicking some button
    page.waitForSelector('.result', {
            timeout: 180000,
            visible: true,
        })
        .then(() => {});
```

Somehow the function `waitForFunction` never run the `return res.status(404)`, even I saw the message shown up and check for the function in the browser console. It returned `true`.

The result won't appear if the message appear.
The message won't appear if the result appear.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fn="document.querySelector('div#message').textContent.includes('string inside message')"

await page.waitForFunction(fn, {timeout: 2000});
const result = await page.evaluate(fn)

if (result===true)
    return res.status(404).json({ success: true, data: null, message: 'Message' });
```

ps. you need to change your express function with: `async function` or `async () =>`

Edit:

await page.waitForFunction('func...', {timeout: 2000});

Comment: Problem is that the `div#message` does not have value at the start, it ran some calculation and then return message. Here I want puppeteer to wait for 2 event, which event return value first is the one my API response, and dispose the other.

Comment: i didn't understand exactly what you need. Currently yours is a non-blocking code, so it is likely that the result of the first promise (the return res.status (404) etc ...) will never be executed. I changed the answer slightly: it waits for 2 seconds for the fn to become true. If true, 404 returns, otherwise execution proceeds